# Want to Add a submit button instead of Enter key

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a Submit button instead of Enter key

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="logsarchives" id="logsarchives" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Enter Console Command" onkeydown="redirect(this)">
    </body>
    <script>
        function redirect(ele) {
            if(event.key === 'Enter') {
                if(ele.value === 'google')
                     window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
                else
                    alert("Invalid");
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `onkeydown="redirect(this)"` from your `<input>` and add the submit button along with the wrapper form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://where.you.want/to/process">
    <input type="text" name="logsarchives" id="logsarchives" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Enter Console Command">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit>
</form>
```